# Corollary of Poincaré-Lemma

Tags: vector-fields, exterior-algebra

In the script of my professor, there is the following corollary of the Poincaré Lemma:

> If $\mathcal F$ is a vector field with rot$(\mathcal F)=0$ and $U\subset\mathbb R^n$ is an open ball, then there is a function $f:U\to\mathbb R$ with grad$(f)=\mathcal F$.

Could anyone make clear how this follows directly from the Poincaré Lemma? I don't really see it. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Poincaré lemma say us that in a contractible domain (as it is an open ball) a closed form is exact. This means that if rot$(f)=0$ (the form is closed) there is a (scalar) field $F$ such that $f$ is its external derivative (it is **exact**), i.e.: $ f=$grad$(F)$, so that rot$($grad$(F))=0$

Comment: Note: simply connected is not enough - you need star-shaped...

Comment: @EduardTetzlaff: thank you for the clarification. I  modified my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Poincare lemma says that all closed forms are exact forms. So if $\mbox{rot}(F)=0$ what can you say about the exactness of $F$?